# log rotation --Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, logrotate

I am looking into log rotation for our web server (not apache) on Windows. I have heard of cronolog, CHOMP, and others. Does Windows have a built-in rotation .exe? What have you found to be a good logrotation application?

Answer (score 2):

Windows automatically ages old log entries and has for years.  Set the max log size or minimum ages and make sure you have the disk space to support your settings.  Settings can be controlled server by server or centrally through group policy.  More here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726966.aspx \

Comment: Does this apply to Couch Database log files, as well? I am new to this sort of thing. They are logged in plain text.

Comment: This isn't the right answer.  The author is asking about text file logging and this answer is about the NT Event log--two different beasts.

Answer (score 2):

You might try [LogRotateWin](http://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/). It implements logrotate on Windows. You configure it with text config files in the same syntax as the Unix logrotate and run it from a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

As much as it's pure evil to risk giving @EvanAnderson more rep by [linking to one of his answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/26883/windows-event-log-rotation), it applies in this case.

> It seems like most people don't know about this feature, but Windows will rotate the log files automatically if so-configured. Look for "AutoBackupLogFiles" in this file.

(Referencing a GPO Administrative Template he's got linked in his answer).

Comment: And how would this relate to logs other than eventlogs ? If it does, please explain.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer This setting only applies to Event Logs (as is generally the case in the Windows world).  Other logs have to be handled individually, but it's not too difficult to whip up a script to do that task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any off the top of my head but you should be able to whip something up via batch files and Scheduled Tasks pretty quickly (PDK).